# How to play Audio file in sequentially in Python?

Tags: python, audio-streaming

I'm working on a project involving streaming audio data. Currently, audio data is split into small fragments(~3 sec) and sent to the client. The client needs to receive it and play it immediately. I've written code to receive and save into .wav file and then play it.
But the sound doesn't play smoothly, it still has a delay between each file.
How can I play it in sequence smoothly:

```
    global c
    c += 1
    print("OPH_LIVE_STREAM")
    file_out = str(c) + filename
    f = open(file_out, "wb")
    f.write(sound)
    f.close
    waffle = str(c-7) + "amthanh.wav"
    playsound(waffle)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Weilory/tkinter-class-music-player

Comment: Have a look at pygame.mixer.music

Comment: What are you using to play the music? What library does playsound come from?

Comment: I install playsound module pip and just use it

Answer (score 0):

Should create a buffer in the client-side and play the audio base on that buffer. It will be smooth I guess.

Comment: Thanks Thông Phạm Bá,
The problem is if I create a buffer, the program must play directly from binary data and I don't know how to play like that. So, I choose to save data to a .wav and play file by file. Do you have any idea ?